# what difference resource using between 'get current_date() on server side' and POST current_date() from client and send to server?

Tags: database, server, web-applications, client

I have a short question.

I want to get a log when people insert some record.

but now developer team get log date from current_date() on client - computer

that would be bad, I don't want users to edit the log when they insert something into the database.

so I asked the dev team to get a current date on the server-side

but they said "if edit that code in all module it might make server and network processing harder and server network will slower"

Does anyone when any idea? it's just a get-current date on the server-side is it a large effect?

Comment: Its depend on the complexity of your project and how you are using it. From your question it is not clear how complex it is and what impact it will have in the project. But at the same time getting current date time on server side is easy.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it will cause a significant effect in your server/network between using a timestamp from server and using a timestamp from client.

But "get log date from `current_date()` on client - computer" that wouldn't be a log anymore.